# Can I use remote google fonts in a wordpress block theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-block-theme

Based on documentation I'm reading, it looks like wordpress block themes only support local fonts and this move was due to a gdpr violation by google fonts.  I further read that google fonts no longer violates gdpr as a result.

I would still like to use remote google fonts, one big factor for this is allowing a site editor to try out different fonts with the theme.  It would be great for them to choose from any of the google fonts without having to edit the theme.

Is this possible ?  If so, how ?